# Как добавить 2 строки в начало и в конец уже существующего файла?

Tags: php

Есть XML файл test.xml следующего содержания:

```
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
```

Как в начало и в конец добавить по две строки `<Catalog><Category>` ... `</Catalog></Category>`, чтобы результатом был сохранен файл со следующим содержанием:

```
<Catalog>
<Category>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site> 
</Category>
</Catalog>
```

Вряд ли такое возможно, но вдруг.
Кучу способов перепробовал и не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Как в начало и в конец добавить по две строки*

Прочитать файл в переменную, обернуть в необходимые теги, и перезаписать исходный файл:

```
$file = __DIR__ . '\test.xml'; // Путь к файлу

$str_put = "<Catalog>\n<Category>\n";
$str_put .= file_get_contents($file);
$str_put .= "\n</Category>\n</Catalog>";

file_put_contents($file, $str_put);
```

Результат:

```
<Catalog>
<Category>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
<Site> еще вложенные классы </Site>
</Category>
</Catalog>
```

Comment: Эдуард, большое вам спасибо, уже который раз выручаете меня!